# useEffect with callback not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to re-render a component to hide or show a 'Use current location' button when the user blocks or allows their location to be known (by clicking on the info icon to the left of the browser address in Chrome). I'm totally confused by why the first example below works, (ie. the button toggled appropriately as soon as the permission is changed) but the second doesn't (it requires a refresh).

I was attemping to remove the duplicate `permission.state !== 'denied'` by simply defining the constant `hasPermission`.

Also, I don't clean up the onchange listener. How do I do this? Can I just assign to null or delete the property?

Works:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then(permission => {
            setHasPermission(permission.state !== 'denied')
            permission.onchange = () =>
                setHasPermission(permission.state !== 'denied')
        })
    }, [])
```

Doesn't work:

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then(permission => {
        const hasPermission = permission.state !== 'denied';
        setHasPermission(hasPermission)
        permission.onchange = () => 
            setHasPermission(hasPermission)
    })
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `permission.onchange` is defined only once.

So, when you define, in your second example, `permission.onchange = () => setHasPermission(hasPermission)` you create an event listener that will *always* call `setHasPermission` with the same value: the result of `permission.state !== 'denied'` saved above.

In your first example, it works because `permission.state !== 'denied'` is evaluated in the event callback.

Is it clear enough ?

For cleanup, `useEffect` can return a function that will be called when component unmounts. Please check https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

Comment: wrt cleanup: with an event listener defined with addEventListener I would removeEventListener in cleanup but how to do it in this case, e.g. would this work: `permission.onChange = null`

Comment: I never used permission, but i believe setting it to null would work as expected. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PermissionStatus/onchange you can also use addEventListener syntax and thus remove it using removeEventListener. Both should work without side effect, but i'm not 100% sure.